# Is there a custom firmware availble for the Canon 450D Rebel XSi?

Tags: canon, canon-450d, firmware, firmware-hacks

Does the Canon 450d have custom firmware? Doing a quick Google search didn't really find anything. And, along similar lines, is the 450d even capable of flashing its firmware? Or are we basically stuck with the stock firmware the camera comes with?

Comment: Deja vu... here's a similar question on [custom firmware for the Nikon D90](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/is-there-custom-firmware-available-for-the-nikon-d90).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware it doesn't, CHDK only runs on the 400D and lower (due to the firmware chipset it ran it was fairly hackable), and Magic Lantern starts on 500D and goes up from there.

Comment: Current CHDK does not work on DSLRs at all. Was there an earlier version that did?

Comment: http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/400D think they ended up going down a different route with the project in the end.

Comment: That project is now at http://code.google.com/p/400plus/, and as of Dec 2011 appears to still be in active development. Cool! And while it's hard to prove a negative, I think the fact that _they_ say they don't support other models and [Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Lantern_Firmware_Wiki), as you say, starts at 500D, it seems like your "no" answer is pretty conclusive.

Comment: I actually looked into it a bit more, the old old processors basically ran a controller that was fairly wide open to replacement, which made firmware hacking an absolute breeze, when the 450D dropped with a new processor in they'd moved to a different supplier and everything was hardened. Then the 500D was another new processor with it's own weaknesses, and Magic Lantern appeared.